# Refresh Hazelcast Cache in Payara

Tags: jakarta-ee, hazelcast, payara

I have an application in JEE on Payara, in which one of the functionalities is loading and displaying an image by the application every 5 minutes from an external server. The problem is that in order to display this picture you have to reset Payara every time. 
Probably the problem is the cache in Payara (data grid). However, I don't know how to change the configuration so that cache refreshes itself. I was looking at the data grid configuration and didn't find anything like that. Could you tell us how to do that?

Comment: Are you using Hazelcast? If yes, could you share your configuration?

Comment: @Nicolas I admit I don't know where the configuration is. I didn't find a hazelcast-config.xml file. Only what is the configuration of this in GUI Payara. I also found references to Hazel in EclipseLink configuration: eclipselink.cache. coordination.protocol and eclipselink.cache.coordination.channel . Maybe you need to configure something here? [I'm sorry for the stupid questions, but this is a sit-down project I'm dealing with for the first time and I don't have much experience with JEE environment].

Comment: I'm afraid it has nothing to do with Hazelcast, but with Payara itself. I don't know about any specifics there. I'd suggest you remove the hazelcast tag.